# Buscar através do ID e atributo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como buscar uma `div` por exemplo através de seu ID e Atributo em especifico como esta:

```
   <div id="Y" data-id="X"></div>
```

ou seja, um código que pegue uma DIV com `id=Y` e `data-id=X`

Comment: Vi que mudaste a resposta aceite. Não tenho nada contra a resposta do Ricardo, mas fico curioso se havia algo errado com a minha resposta?

Comment: @Sergio não marcarei nenhum e esperarei os votos subirem, você foi rápido e mostrou o que eu queria, ele foi prestativo e deu seu tempo a me ajudar, fico realmente divido, ótima resposta à sua.

Comment: Podes deixar marcada a resposta do Ricardo, ele está essencialmente certa. Queria mesmo só saber se há algo na minha resposta que não fosse útil. Agora já sei que ambas foram úteis. Em relação a votar a comunidade vai votar na mesma ao longo do tempo. Tu é que escolhes qual é certa/aceite.

Answer (score 2):

Para buscar por ambos (Redundante):

```
$('#Y[data-id="X"]').html('hauahu');
```

Para buscar pelo `id` é desta forma com `javascript` puro:

```
var x = document.getElementById("Y");
```

Para buscar pela classe (ira retornar um array com todos os objetos com determinada classe):

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
```

Ou usando jquery:

```
$("ul").find("[data-id=X]");
```

É basicamente esta a construção de seletores, estes que podem ser utilizados em uma variedade de funções da `jquery`.

Para buscar por seletores difenciados pode-se usar esta construção (suportadas por todos os browsers **Atuais**).

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('[property]');
```

Fontes que dizem que o atibuto `id` deve ser único:

[W3 test](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/tests/test185.html)

[Prgrammers pergunta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

[Documentção W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id)

Answer (score 2):

Se queres encontrar um elemento com *ambos* os atributos podes usar

```
var div = document.querySelector('#Y[data-id="X"]');
// ou ainda:
var div = document.querySelector('[id="Y"][data-id="X"]');
```

Neste exmplo fica redundante usar `data-id="X"` pois o `#Y` deve ser sufeciente uma vez que IDs têm de ser únicos. Mas em caso de outro attributo `data-` ou classe podes usar assim:

```
var div = document.querySelector('.minhaClass[data-id="X"]'); 
// ou noutros casos
var div = document.querySelector('[data-custom="Y"][data-id="X"]');
```

Ou seja: os seletores de CSS devem estar juntos, sem espaço, quando a ideia fôr selecionar um elemento com ambos os atributos.