# Encontrar 2 atributos data em um unico elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como consigo encontrar um determinadoa atributo que contenha um outro determinato atributo especifico? por exemplo:

```
<a class="fc-draggable" data-belongs="3" data-target="2"></a>
```

Eu consigo selecionar todos os elementos que contenham um determinado atributo usando:

```
$('*[data-belongs="3"]');
```

Mas como faço para selecionar todos os `data-belongs='2'` que contenham `data-target='3'`?

Comment: Já testaste `$('[data-belongs="2"][data-target="3"]');`?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67901/129

Comment: @Sergio se qu quiser selecionar todos que `não tenham` este atributo como eu faria? `$('a[data-belongs]').not('[data-belongs="'+current+'"][data-target="'+target+'"]').hide();` ?

Comment: Exato... assim funcionaria

Comment: @Sergio, poste a resposta para eu confirmar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar `$('[data-belongs="2"][data-target="3"]');` [como referi em comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154634/encontrar-2-atributos-data-em-um-unico-elemento/154722#comment319080_154634), assim procuras elementos com ambos os atributos.

Para selecionar através dos atributos de elemento podemos usar os seletores de atributos seguidos uns aos outros.

Para filtrar depois podemos usar o `.not()` assim:

```
$('a[data-belongs]').not('[data-belongs="' + nr + '"][data-‌​target="' + nr + '"]‌​').hide();
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/k9h3kka3/

Answer (score 4):

Tenta isso:

```
$('*[data-belongs="2"][data-target="3"]');
```

Fonte: [jQuery: Seletor de atributo múltiplo](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)